# How to connect (pair) two CC41-A module

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, at-commands

I bought two CC41-A BT modules. First I want to buy HM10 modules. I wonder if I can connect this two CC41-A to send and read data wirelessly. I look in datasheet but I cant find suitable AT command (I think I need some like AT+CONN). Is it possible to connect this two modules or I must buy orginal HM10?

Comment: Datasheet links, please.

Comment: Here is datasheet: https://img.banggood.com/file/products/20150104013145BLE-CC41-A%20Spefication.pdf

Comment: And here avaliable  AT commands: https://halckemy.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/94325/FE85NGOIH90OKGT.pdf

Comment: Excellent! I recommend you post that as an *answer* to your own question, instead of as a comment. Answers can be upvoted and are much more visible than comments!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if I should answer to my own question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by an asker who has not returned to the site to accept their self-answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know that I can vote for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolve problem myself. So I write instruction if anyone in future will have similar problem. The problem is that one of the pairing modules must be in master role and second in slave role. When device is in master role, the user have access to the additional AT commands, which are unaccessible in slave mode. So in short, to pair two modules we must: - set one module to master, second to slave (AT+ROLE0, AT+ROLE1) - in master we search available slaves (AT+INQ) - and then we can connect to the slave we want (AT+CONNx).

Comment: Please accept your self-answer so that the question shows as resolved.